# Advanced WHERE clause inside left join with multiple condition doesn't work using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to generate the following SQL query using Eloquent ORM

```
select * from table_1 
left join table_2 on table_2.id = table_1.id 
    and table_2.offline <= ? 
    and (
        table_2.online >= ? or table_2.online= ?
    )
```

Although applying different approach suggested in stackoverflow and other site to get the parenthesis () betwenn AND-0R clause, I cannot get the desired result. Sample Eloquent query:

```
        Capsule::table('table_1')
        ->leftJoin('table_2', function ($join) use ($from, $until) {
            $join->on('table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.id')
                ->where('table_2.offline', '<=', $until)
                ->where(function($q) use ($from) {
                    $q->where('table_2.online', '>=', $from)
                        ->orWhere('table_2.online', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                });
        })
        ->toSql();
```

This is what I am getting currently from the above Eloquent query as raw sql.

```
select * from `table_1` 
left join `table_2` 
    on `table_2`.`id` = `table_1`.`id` 
    and `table_2`.`offline` <= ? and   ?
```

The whole Advanched where clause is changed to ?. Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Works just fine in 5.5

Comment: It seems I am using   -> illuminate/database": "~4.2". Doesn't work at this version.

Comment: 4.2 is pretty old in the Laravel world, you might want to mention that in future questions. My assumption is that you should move the where conditions outside of the join closure, they really don't belong there anyways.

Comment: @Devon Correct me if I am wrong, it seems that i will not get my desired SQL query if I put it out of the join closure. Can you suggest any alternative?

Comment: You'd be wrong.  There's no need for the join closure.

Comment: WholeQuery:Capsule::table('table_1')
            ->leftJoin('table_2', function ($join) use ($from, $until) {
                $join->on('table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.id')
                    ->where('table_2.offline', '<=', $until)
                    ->where(function($q) use ($from) {
                        $q->where('table_2.online', '>=', $from)
                            ->orWhere('table_2.online', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                    });
            })
            ->where()
            ->whereIn()
            ->groupBy()
            ->select()
            ->get();

Comment: @Devon I posted small fraction of my query! It has more where clause below. Again, I fell sorry for not posting whole query as I think it would be too long and there is not any plm in other parts of query.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 you should enable query logging by:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

Then after placing your final statement:

```
DB::table('table_1')
        ->leftJoin('table_2', function ($join) use ($from, $until) {
            $join->on('table_2.id', '=', 'table_1.id')
                ->where('table_2.offline', '<=', $until)
                ->where(function($q) use ($from) {
                    $q->where('table_2.online', '>=', $from)
                        ->orWhere('table_2.online', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                });
        })
        ->get();
```

just run:

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

it will return the SQL and the bindings of the last queries that were executed.
In Laravel 4 queryLogging is enabled by default, so you can just dump the query log.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using Laravel 4 and logging is enabled. I have also pasted the log output query in my question. But I cannot get the desired result which i am looking for.

Comment: run dd(DB::getQueryLog()); it will returns bindings too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get dd(DB::getQueryLog()); to run. I try:
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;
{...queries...}
dd(DB::getQueryLog());

I got following error:
PHP Strict standards:  Non-static method Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::getQueryLog() should not be called statically in /home/virta/site/trunk/wwwroot/admin/dashboard/Database.php on line 456